# Find the next symbol in this sequence

Tags: pattern

I just came up with the following puzzle. I don't think anything like this has been asked here before, but I may be wrong.

What's the next symbol in this sequence?

[image: (ヨ, ミ, ワ, something, something, something]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 /\     /      /\     /             /\           
/ /\   / /    /  \   /        /\   /        / 
 / /    / /   \  /   \  /    /     \  /   \/  
  /      /      /      /             /     \
```

Hint

> $\pi$ and xor

Spoiler

> Write the digits of pi on a 7-segment display and generate every symbol in the sequence by combining the previous symbol with the next digit of $\pi$ with an xor.  Start with all segments off.

Comment: Yes! Well done.

Comment: Can you please explain it to me? I dont understand "π and xor". Thanks.

Comment: π = 3.1415926 and XOR = exclusive or.

Comment: So, for example, how do you get the first symbol combining 3 and 1?

Comment: Oops, the explanation was wrong.  I reformulated it.

Comment: @klm123 The second symbol in the sequence is made from '3' on a seven segment display (like on a digital alarm clock) and then any of the segments also present in the display of '1' are toggled to off